# C++ - the count of the array is irrelevant to the declared size

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written the following code block. But the size of the array returned by `sizeof()` is irrelevant. I have an array of 6 elements while the `sizeof()` returns 24 as the size of the array.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = { 0, 5, 8, 32, 100, 41 };
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr);
    int i = 0;
    cout << "This is the Size of Array: " << arrSize << endl;
    /*
    for (i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)
    {
      cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }   */

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the Output:

```
This is the Size of Array: 24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

This would find total size of array ie. here `6 * 4 = 24` and then divide it by single element size, hence `24/4 = 6`

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` gives the size of the data in *bytes*

6 * 4 byte integers = 24 *bytes*

Comment: How the should I get the count of an array?